# Ruby FileList filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filelist

I have a `FileList` with `*.js` and `*.tc` extensions. How can I split it into two arrays of `FileList`, one with only `*.js` files and the other with `*.tc` files?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `File.extname` to get the extension of a file name, and `Array#group_by` to group array members with similarities:

```
result = [ "aaa.js", "bbb.js", "ccc.js", 
           "xxx.tc", "yyy.tc", "zzz.tc" ].group_by { |fname| File.extname(fname) }

=> { ".js" => ["aaa.js", "bbb.js", "ccc.js"], 
     ".tc" => ["xxx.tc", "yyy.tc", "zzz.tc"] }
```

Now you have a `Hash` containing two arrays (`result[".js"]` and `result[".tc"]`) that contain the file names according to their extensions.

Comment: `.group_by(&File.method(:extname))`.

Comment: To get what the OP asked for (which I doubt it is actually useful), `values` can be applied to the result of `group_by`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Enumerable#partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) comes to the rescue.

```
["aaa.js", "bbb.js", "ccc.js",
 "xxx.tc", "yyy.tc", "zzz.tc" ].partition do |e|
    e[/(?<=\.).*\z/] == "tc"
  end
#⇒ [["xxx.tc", "yyy.tc", "zzz.tc"],
#   ["aaa.js", "bbb.js", "ccc.js"]]
```

or, more explicit:

```
["aaa.js", "bbb.js", "ccc.js",
 "xxx.tc", "yyy.tc", "zzz.tc" ].partition(&/\.tc\z/.method(:=~))
```

Comment: As we are kind of golfing here :) with comments: `.partition {|f| f =~ /js$/}` seems more straight-forward to me. and `end_with?('js')` more readable.